# How to Access the CheckBox Value in ASP.NET MVC without using method parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use the following HTML helper to generate check box:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("DeluxeFeature")%>
```

Now I want to access the value of this checkbox in my controller. How should I do this? I am not going to use the method parameter name, for the reason that there are a lot of checkboxes and putting all of them in the parameter will clutter the method.

I try to use

```
Request.Form["DeluxeFeature"]
```

But the behavior is very weird; if the checkbox is not ticked, then the `Request.Form["DeluxeFeature"]` returns "`false`", which is expected. But if the checkbox is ticked, then it retruns "`true, false`".

Very weird, isn't it?

Comment: is there something else in your form named "DeluxeFeature"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx) on the asp.net forums explains the behavior - there's even a comment by Phil Haack from the ASP.NET MVC project team (bonus!!).

So the best way to handle it if you're not using the helpers/model binders as posted by levib seems to be

```
Request.Form.GetValues("DeluxeFeature")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
var checkbox = Request.Form.Get("DeluxeFeature");
if (checkbox.Contains("true"))
{
    //Whatever code if the checkbox is checked.
}
```